# querySelector syntax for nested elements

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

I'm trying to get the div element that's nested deep within another div, but can't get the CSS Selector string to work.

The div I want does not have a unique identifier, but resides deep within another div that has. I've gotten that top level div, but have no clue how to get the nested one.

DOM:

```js
var obj = document.body.querySelector('.qvobject[data-qlikobjectid="XFvnjF"]');
console.log(obj);

var cont = obj.querySelector('.kpi-value');
console.log(cont);
```

```html
<div class="qvobject" data-qlikobjectid="XFvnjF">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="kpi-value">I WANT THIS</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The result is that "obj" is the right object, but "cont" is null, so it can't find it.

Comment: your code, in snippet working, right?

Comment: Yeah even without running the snippet that's now been added I can't see how cont could possibly be null in that situation.

Comment: Seems like you can't reproduce the issue in your question.

Comment: Yes it seems to be working here. I can't replicate with this code, because it is "thinned down". My DOM tree is bigger and with different data. It seems I need to review the structure itself, if this works.

Comment: Check for nested frames or shadowdom. It should work otherwise .

Answer (score 1):

You can select it using the [descendent combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator). Just put a space between the parent selector and the child selector.

This makes the traverser go further to any level in the dom to select the desired element.

```js
var element = document.querySelector('.qvobject[data-qlikobjectid="XFvnjF"] .kpi-value');

console.log(element);
```

```html
<div class="qvobject" data-qlikobjectid="XFvnjF">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="kpi-value">I WANT THIS</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but it doesn't work. I first thought the DOM wasn't loaded, but I see the element in the innerHTML, so it is there.

Comment: Is it nested within shadow roots?

Comment: Nitpick: The space character in CSS selectors is [the _descendant_ combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator), not the "child" selector; [the child combinator is actually `>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator).